# How do I remove an attribute and an element if an ancestor's attribute holds a certain value using xsl

Tags: xslt, ancestor, remove-if

I am struggling with the following issue:
In the below XML, I need to remove the attribute restrict="restrict" if the attribute is nested within an element that also contains an attribute restrict="restrict". I also need to remove the element restrict if it is nested within an element containing an attribute restrict="restrict". However, if a restrict="restrict" appears on a nested element whose ancestor does not contain an attribute restrict="restrict", I need to keep it. The same goes for the restrict element. I need to keep it if it is not nested in a restrict element or within an element that does not have the restrict="restrict" attribute.

```
<book hasrestrict="yes"> 
<story> <part partno="1"> <parttitle>Title of the Part</parttitle> 
<chapter chapno="11"> <chaptertitle>Title of the Chapter</chaptertitle> 
<section id="id3321234" secno="23">
<sectiontitle>Title of the Section</sectiontitle> 
<toc/> 
<subsection1 restrict="restrict">
<date>(09-23-2012)</date> 
<title>Subsection Title</title> 
<p>Text that makes up the paragraph of the subsetion1. <restrict>This information is  
restricted.</restrict></p> 
<p restrict="restrict">Here is some text in another paragraph that is
restricted. The restrict attribute of the paragraph needs to be
removed because a restrict attribute is already specified for
subsection1. Everything that appears within the element of subsection
1 is already restricted, so I need to remove the unnecessary restrict
attribute from the paragraph because it is causing havoc when my
publishing system tries to format the document.</p>
<subsection2><title>Title of Subsection2</title> 
<p>This is text that appears in a subsecion2 paragraph. 
<list><li>This is an item in a list <restrict>that has restricted content</restrict></li>
<li>Second item</li> 
<li>Third item</li></list></p> 
<subsection3 restrict="restrict">
<title>Title of Subsection3</title> 
<p>Text appearing in a paragraph in subsction 3 
<table frame="all"> <tgroup cols="3" colsep="1" rowsep="1"> 
<colspec colname="col1"/> <colspec colname="col2"/> 
<colspec colname="col3"/>
<thead><row><entry>Entry1</entry>
<entry>Entry2</entry>
<entry>Entry3 <restrict>with restricted information</restrict></entry></row></thead>
<tbody><row><entry restrict="restrict">text</entry>
<entry>text</entry>
<entry>text</entry></row>
</tbody></tgroup></table></p></subsection3></subsection2></subsection1>
<subsection1><date>(09-23-2012)</date> 
<title>Subsection Title</title>
<p>Text that makes up the paragraph of the subsetion1. <restrict>This information is
restricted.</restrict></p> 
<p restrict="restrict">Here is some text in another paragraph that is
restricted. </p> 
<subsection2 restrict="restrict"><title>Title of Subsection2</title>
<p>This is text that appears in a subsecion2 paragraph.</p>
</subsection2></subsection1></section></chapter></part></story></book>
```

I am new to xsl, and have attempted to write the translation, but I am not having much luck.

The desired out put should look like this:

```
<book hasrestrict="yes">
<story>
<part partno="1">
<parttitle>Title of the Part</parttitle>
<chapter chapno="11">
<chaptertitle>Title of the Chapter</chaptertitle>
<section id="id3321234" secno="23">
<sectiontitle>Title of the Section</sectiontitle>
<toc/>
<subsection1 restrict="restrict"><date>(09-23-2012)</date>
<title>Subsection Title</title>
<p>Text that makes up the paragraph of the subsetion1. This information is restricted.</p>
<p>Here is some text in another paragraph that is restricted. The restrict attribute of the paragraph needs to be removed because a restrict attribute is already specified for subsection1. Everything that appears within the element of subsection1 is already restricted, so I need to remove the unnecessary restrict attribute from the paragraph because it is causing havoc when my publishing system tries to format the document.</p>
<subsection2><title>Title of Subsection2</title>
<p>This is text that appears in a subsecion2 paragraph.
<list>
<li>This is an item in a list that has restricted content</li>
<li>Second item</li>
<li>Third item</li></list></p>
<subsection3><title>Title of Subsection3</title>
<p>Text appearing in a paragraph in subsction 3
<table frame="all">
<tgroup cols="3" colsep="1" rowsep="1">
<colspec colname="col1"/>
<colspec colname="col2"/>
<colspec colname="col3"/>
<thead><row><entry>Entry1</entry>
<entry>Entry2</entry>
<entry>Entry3 with restricted information</entry></row></thead>
<tbody><row>text</entry>
<entry>text</entry>
<entry>text</entry></row></tbody></tgroup></table></p></subsection3></subsection2></subsection1>
<subsection1><date>(09-23-2012)</date>
<title>Subsection Title</title><p>Text that makes up the paragraph of the subsetion1. <restrict>This information is restricted.</restrict></p>
<p restrict="restrict">Here is some text in another paragraph that is restricted. </p>
<subsection2 restrict="restrict"><title>Title of Subsection2</title><p>This is text that appears in a subsecion2 paragraph.</p></subsection2></subsection1></section></chapter></part></story></book>
```

Here is the code I have attempted:

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@restrict">
  <xsl:if test="ancestor::*[@restrict='restrict']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="restrict">
  <xsl:if test="ancestor::*[@restrict='restrict']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="restrict"> 
  <xsl:if test="ancestor::restrict">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>     
</xsl:transform>
```

This is not working for me. I receive an error stating

"WARNING org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The child axis starting at an attribute node will never select anything"

I really don't know how to go about doing this. Any suggestions (and explanation) would be greatly 
appreciated.

Comment: That's actually a warning, not an error -- the transform still succeeds. The warning is letting you know that your 
`<xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>`

is not going to do anything. Can you explain more what part of the current XSLT output is problematic?

Comment: I am not achieving the desired output. If the ancestor (let's use subsection1) has an attribute of restrict, then I need to remove all of the restrict attributes on every descendent as well as every restrict element contained within subsection 1. However, if the ancestor does not contain a restrict attribute, I need to keep the restrict elements and attributes of the descendants, but I cannot have a restrict element nested within a restrict element. When I run the above code, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the identity template, you don't really need to code extra logic for the elements or attributes you wish to keep; whether they are `restrict` ones or not. You only really need to add templates for the things you wish to remove.

You say "*need to remove the attribute restrict="restrict" if the attribute is nested within an element that also contains an attribute restrict="restrict*". Well, the template to do this would be like so:

```
<xsl:template match="../ancestor::*[@restrict='restrict']]" />
```

(The .. here is to ignore the current element which has the current `restrict` element)

And to "*to remove the element restrict if it is nested within an element containing an attribute restrict="restrict".*", the template would look like this

```
<xsl:template match="restrict[ancestor::*[@restrict='restrict']]" />
```

Having said that, you mention about keeping `restrict` elements if they are not nested in a restrict element or within an element that does not have the restrict="restrict" attribute. In this case, the templates may need to look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="@restrict[../ancestor::restrict or ../ancestor::*[@restrict='restrict']]" />
<xsl:template match="restrict[ancestor::restrict or ancestor::*[@restrict='restrict']]" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@restrict[../ancestor::restrict or ../ancestor::*[@restrict='restrict']]" />        
    <xsl:template match="restrict[ancestor::restrict or ancestor::*[@restrict='restrict']]" /> 
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and assistance. I truly appreciate your help. This XSLT does mostly what I want, but it removes the restrict attribute from the first subsection1 that is not nested within a restrict.

Comment: I've amended my answer to handle this situation.

Comment: I just tried the amended answer, but the restrict attribute is still removed. It is odd because there aren't any restrict attributes set on the ancestors and it isn't contained within a restrict element, so why would it be stripped?

Comment: Would it be possible to edit your question to re-format the XML to make it bit more readable, so it is easier to see where the attributes are? I also noticed your XSLT refers to a namespace (irs). Does you XML actually use namespaces in reality? Thanks!

Comment: I see the issue now! I've updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Wow! Thanks. This takes care of the subsection1 attribute. However, when I run it against my documents, I am seeing that restrict elements nested inside of p elements that are nested inside of a subsection1 with a restrict attribute are not being removed. I thought they would be because of the "ancestor::*[@restrict='restrict']" match?

Comment: Are you sure they are nested and not siblings? Can you perhaps edit your question to include another example? Thanks!

Comment: My apologies. It was my application. I used a different processor and it worked! Thank you so much for all of your help. As mentioned, this is all new to me. I am slowly learning, but I think that getting some training would do me well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove the attribute restrict="restrict" if the attribute is nested within an element that also contains an attribute restrict="restrict". -->
<xsl:template match="@restrict[.='restrict'][parent::*/ancestor::*/@restrict='restrict']"/>


<!-- remove the element restrict if it is nested within an element containing an attribute restrict="restrict".  -->
<xsl:template match="restrict[ancestor::*/@restrict='restrict']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is almost what I am looking for. I also need to remove the restrict element if it appears within another restrict element. Additionally, when I run this against my xml, the restrict element nested in a p nested in a subsection1 with a restrict attribute is not being removed.

Comment: As I mentioned above, the restrict element, nested in a p, nested in a subsection1 with a restrict attribute was removed when I used a different processor. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't really follow the nuances. I think you have the basis to make the necessary changes yourself, though.